# Can two iOS developer accounts use the same paid bank account

Tags: ios, accounts, developer-program

I have two questions regarding using multiple developer accounts.

I have two iOS individual developer accounts. Can the two developer accounts use the same bank account?

If one of my developer account get terminated by Apple for some reasons, does it affects the second account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things may have changed since I set up my developer accounts, but based on my experience from years ago, **yes** this is fine. Payment is taken through the Apple Store, so you can just provide the same payment information when purchasing both programmes.